# Revert some Git commits, keep others?

Tags: git

Suppose I make commits A, B, and C, all of which touched entirely different codepaths. (So they're independent and commit B can exist without the changes in A, and so on.)

Commit A introduced a bug, while commits B and C are fine. So I want to revert to the state of my code before commit A, and then commit changes B and C.

What's the best way to do this? One way is to simply do a `git revert <SHA-of-commit-before-A>` and then manually add back in commits B and C -- is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to add back `B` and `C`: they are already committed and won't be impacted by your revert which add a new commits (negative image of `A`).

Another way is (**if you don't have already pushed those commits**) to do an interactive rebase (`git rebase -i A^`), and reorder your commits, dropping `A` completely.
You will see in your rebase the following options (see [git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages))

```
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

But again, that will change your history and will make you a git push --force, which isn't always a good idea, if other people already have pulled from your repo.
In that case, the revert remains the safest solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you've already pushed your changes (so they are visible to others) the right thing to do is `git-revert <SHA-of-A>`.  That explicitly makes a new commit that's the opposite of A.  If no one has seen your tree yet you can use `git-rebase -i A^` (where `A^` means "parent of A") to interactively reorder or omit commits since A.  In this case you could remove A and it would do exactly what you described (unwind to just before A and then reapply only B and C).

Comment: Same advice (minus the "change history" caveat) 46 seconds before my answer ;) +1